# permanently allocate memory in embedded system

Tags: c, memory, embedded, busybox

My requirement is very simple. 
I have ubuntu running on an embedded platform. I want to allocate some permanent location in memory (I know what address DRAM starts). All I want is that the memory should not be touched by OS and I can perform custom operations on that memory (such as collect some statistical data and write to that location).

The requirements are:

1. Allocate some location in memory (the OS allocated the memory and returns me back the address is fine with me).
2. This location should be there till the OS is running.
3. Size is one parameter.
4. I want to read and write to this location using busybox devmem kind of commands.

Comment: This is not an answer. Perhaps your problem is easy, I mean, maybe you could use Redis, SQLite or one of a bunch of lightweight dbs out there (in memory db). wiki.debian.org/ramfs ... Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bigphysarea to allocate some memory at boot time.
the size can be provided in the linux kernel parameters, yous just have to append something like:

```
bigphysarea=2
```

where 2 means 2 pages (2*4K)

this will allow you to allocate a contiguous memory to use by your drivers.

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do, but be aware that this kind of allocation is only accessible from kernel mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount some pieces of memory to the file system, like [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs), and just operate file(s) on the partition.

For example, http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/

Comment: The specific proposal is probably not applicable, as these are backed not by "raw" memory but by the file system caching code, with the result that the contents should only be accessed through that code.  The poster seems to want "raw" memory that can potentially be used before the kernel boots.